# MYSQL Join and show not matching records

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables

```
users

id   name
----------
1.   David
2.   Ben

messages

id.   message   userId
-----------------------
1.    hi.         1
2.    hey.        99
3.    by.         2
```

I need to get these results

```
id.   message   userId.  name
------------------------------
1.    hi.         1.     David
2.    hey.        99
3.    by.         2.     Ben
```

I want to add the name to the results only if the userId matches a record in the user's table but still shows messages that the userId has no match.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
   m.id, 
   m.message, 
   m.userId 
   u.name 
FROM 
   messages m, 
   users u
WHERE
   u.id = m.userId
```

but it doesn't show messages that have no matching user:

```
id.   message   userId.  name
------------------------------
1.    hi.         1.     David
3.    by.         2.     Ben
```

I'm using MySQL v 5.7.26

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
   m.id, 
   m.message, 
   m.userId, 
   u.name 
FROM 
   messages m
LEFT JOIN
   users u on m.userID = u.id
```

Tester here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf952b/2